# How to copy one string's n number of characters to another string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Let's take a string `var str = "Hello Kotlin"`. I want to copy first 5 character of `str` to another variable `strHello`. I was wondering is there any function of doing this or I have to apply a loop and copy characters one by one.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim commented, there's a [`substring()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html) method which does exactly this, so you can simply do:

```
val strHello = str.substring(0, 5)
```

(The first parameter is the 0-based index of the first character to take; and the second is the index of the character to stop before.)

There are many, many methods available on most of the common types.  If you're using an IDE such as IDEA or Eclipse, you should see a list of them pop up after you type `str.`.  (That's one of many good reasons for using an IDE.)  Or check the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/).

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `string.take(n)` utility.

More details at
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html

I was using `substring` in my project, but it gave an exception when the length of the string was smaller than the second index of `substring`.

```
val name1 = "This is a very very long name"

// To copy to another string
val name2 = name1.take(5)

println(name1.substring(0..5))
println(name1.substring(0..50)) // Gives EXCEPTION

println(name1.take(5))
println(name1.take(50)) // No EXCEPTION
```